# Backend validation using a single component in Angular 2

Tags: angular

How to create a single component in Angular 2 through which I can handle all the backend validations in the whole application?

Comment: How do you want to handle backend-validations in a frontend component? Do you mean something like a service where you call the backend from and pass the data to check?

Comment: Please don't do this as long as others have to work with your code, too. It sounds like a quite crappy idea.

Comment: have you tried filters for validations???

Comment: Yes, exactly. Handle all backend validations and errors in some frontend components. I have tried filters, but then I had to write many of them since the application has around 7 to 8 components.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a error handler for responses from the API? This could be achieved through the following:

```
public someFunction(): void {
  this._provider.getData()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      // do something with a success
    }, (error: any) => {
      this._handleError(error);
    })
}

private _handleError(error:any): void {
  if (error.status === 400) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Within the `_handleError()` method you can do whatever you want with specific error codes. This method could be extracted into a single service class and injected into each component and then used like follows: `this._errorService.handleError(error)`. You would need to make the method public then instead of private.

Comment: No, I mean an error handler for responses from different controllers that do the backend job.